# Posting form elements to an api

Tags: php, mysql, forms, xampp, moodle

I am developing a plugin for moodle. I would like to post the values from the moodle form to my API for authentication. Where should I edit/add the specifications for setting the form action and how? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, you should put your specifications in your plugin documentation.

Comment: Hmmm, basically I want to do it this way, <form name='foo' method='post' action='url(myapi)'>. How do I this in moodle?